# Create Ec2 Instance with Terraform code where private key will be stored in AWS Parameter store(type- Secure String)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws, aws-parameter-store

My team wanted to store the private key( By manually storing the SSH Key through AWS Console which was already generated )in the Secure String parameter on AWS SSM parameter store instead of passing the SSH through the terraform code.

Is it possible for me to create EC2 using Terraform by storing SSH key in AWS Parameter store?

If not, then how do I use the SSM param SecureString in my Terraform code to create new EC2 instances?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is expecting that your ssh key is exist. So you need to pass key name in terraform EC2 resources. You can SSH to the server by using existing key.